# How to store items from inside onBindViewHolder to array

Tags: java, android

I have a number of buttons inside recycview
I just wanted to add them in array and then i get them to add to them some jobs.

- At first i defined array name "buttons"
  ToggleButton buttons[] = new ToggleButton[5];
- Then i put values in it 
  buttons[position]=holder.playBtn;
- Now I want to press one of them 
  change all the backgrounds of all buttons 
  And so i used this function :
  closeAll()
  ,but I didn't succeeding

```java
// My class
public class MyListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;
    private MyListData[] listdata;
    private Context context;
    private ToggleButton [] listBtnPlyStop = null;

    ToggleButton buttons[] = new ToggleButton[5];

    public MyListAdapter(Context context ,MyListData[] listdata , RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) {
        this.mListener =mListener;
        this.listdata = listdata;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_azcar, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final MyListData myListData = listdata[position];
        holder.textView.setText(listdata[position].getDescription());
        buttons[position]=holder.playBtn;
        holder.playBtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean checked) {
                mListener.onClick(compoundButton,position);
                setBgBtn(compoundButton,checked,position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void setBgBtn(CompoundButton compoundButton , boolean checked,int id) {
        if(checked){
            compoundButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.btnpause));
        }else{
            compoundButton.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.btnplay));
        }
        closeAll();
    }

    private void closeAll(){
        for(int j=0; j<buttons.length-1;j++) {
            buttons[j].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnpause);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listdata.length;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textView;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;
        public ToggleButton toggleButton,playBtn;
        public RadioButton radioButton1,radioButton2,radioButton3;
        private RecyclerViewClickListener mListener;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            //this.itemView = itemView;
            this.toggleButton =(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_check2);
            this.playBtn =(ToggleButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bt_play);
            this.radioButton1 = (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn1);
            this.radioButton2= (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn2);
            this.radioButton3= (RadioButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.radio_btn3);
            this.textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id._txt_kind_of_azkar);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.l_containe_row);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is happening when you use the `closeAll()` function?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest creating a dynamic array list of ToggleButtons, like so:

```
        private ArrayList<ToggleButton> buttons;

        public MyListAdapter(Context context ,MyListData[] listdata , RecyclerViewClickListener mListener) { 
            this.mListener =mListener;
            this.listdata = listdata;
            this.context = context;
            this.buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            View listItem= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_list_azcar, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
            return viewHolder;
        }


        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            final MyListData myListData = listdata[position];
            holder.textView.setText(listdata[position].getDescription());
            buttons.add(holder.playBtn);

       ...
         private void closeAll(){
            for(int j=0; j<buttons.size(); j++) {
                buttons.get(j).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btnpause);
            }
         }
```